# XSD to JSON schema dynamic conversion JAVA

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jsonschema

I have xsd schema and I need to provide json schema. I saw that it is possible using JAXB and Jackson, but the main issue is that I need to generate class from xsd and only than I can generate json schema.

My goal is to create webservice which:

1. gets xsd from server
2. sends client json schema
3. receives json data
4. converts json data to xml
5. validate xml -> xsd

I have tried using DynamicJAXBContext, ObjectMapper etc. but I was not able to find solution for all steps I have wrote above:

```
FileInputStream xsdInputStream = new FileInputStream("src/example/customer.xsd");
        DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = 
            DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, null, null, null);
```

I have also tried generating .java files and trying to convert them to schema:

```
String outputDirectory = "..............\\src";
SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();

File schemaFile = new File("........\\Desktop\\SalesVal.xsd");
InputSource is = new InputSource(schemaFile.toURI().toString());

sc.parseSchema(is);
S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
JCodeModel jCodeModel = model.generateCode(null, null);
jCodeModel.build(new File(outputDirectory));
for (com.sun.tools.xjc.api.Mapping m : model.getMappings()) {
    writeToStandardOutputWithDeprecatedJsonSchema(createJaxbObjectMapper(), m.getType()
                                                                             .getTypeClass()
                                                                             .fullName());
```

```
static private void writeToStandardOutputWithDeprecatedJsonSchema(final ObjectMapper mapper,
                                                                  final String fullyQualifiedClassName) {
    try {
        final JsonSchema jsonSchema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName));
        System.out.println(jsonSchema);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
        System.err.println("Unable to find class " + fullyQualifiedClassName);
    } catch (JsonMappingException jsonEx) {
        System.err.println("Unable to map JSON: " + jsonEx);
    }
}

static private ObjectMapper createJaxbObjectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    // make deserializer use JAXB annotations (only)
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    // make serializer use JAXB annotations (only)
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);
    return mapper;
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? can you share?

Comment: @YeshwantKAKAD I am not 100% sure but I think I was not able to make this to work.

Comment: @LukasIgnatavičius is it still undone?

Comment: @YeshwantKAKAD I am also finding the same solution. Did you find any related to it?

Comment: Hi @LukasIgnatavičius, Did you get the answer? if yes can you please share?

Comment: Sorry I do not remember, it was quite some time ago